# Avoid contents from collapsing on Bootstrap 5 grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid, bootstrap-5

Whats up friends, great friday for yous!

So I been rebuilding the website for the company I work to learn HTML+CSS.
Just doing a replica of the original website and its been going great.

So I am having some issues on the the footer right now, the items are mixing on smaller screens.

On the image below you can see (1) how it is and the desired result and (2) what is happening with me.

[image]

Here is my code:

```css
.footer {

    color: #fff;
    height: 140px;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #130936, #130936) no-repeat center;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;

}


.container {

width: 70%;

}

p, p a {

    text-decoration:none;
    color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.72);
    letter-spacing: 0.3px;
    font-size:14px;

}

.footer-brand {
    width: 136px;
    background: url(https://i.ibb.co/zbq2q4D/pngwing-com-1.png) left center no-repeat;
    border: 0;
    text-indent: -99999px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

i {

color: #fff;
font-size: 30px;
padding-left: 4px;
padding-right: 4px;
text-align: center;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
</head>
<body>
    <footer class="footer">

        <div class="container-md h-100">
            <div class="row align-items-center h-100 row-cols-4">
                <div class="col-3"><img class="footer-brand" src="https://i.ibb.co/zbq2q4D/pngwing-com-1.png" alt=""></div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <p class="p1"><a href="tel:+44 (0) 700 677 1336">+44 (0) 700 677 1336</a></p>
                    <p><a href="mailto:info@jpadsolutions.com">info@companyIwork.com</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3 text-center">
                    <a href="#"><i class="bi bi-facebook"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="bi bi-twitter"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="bi bi-instagram"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="bi bi-linkedin"></i></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <p>© 2022 - TheCompanyIWork Limited</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    </footer>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>      
</body>
</html>
```

I do appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're missing is the use of the responsiveness prefixes for the col class, when you declare `col` or `col-x` as a class it means that the class would automatically be with a fixed size in relation to the other grids, to overcome content overlapping you'll need to the prefixed to determine the screen size from which the content is being displayed upon i.e `col-sm-x, col-md-x` etc

Read more about bootstrap grid from here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/layout/grid/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <footer class="footer">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 text-center">
            <img
              class="footer-brand image-fluid"
              src="https://i.ibb.co/zbq2q4D/pngwing-com-1.png"
              alt=""
              style="width:80px"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 text-center">
            <p class="p1">
              <a href="tel:+44 (0) 700 677 1336">+44 (0) 700 677 1336</a>
            </p>
            <p>
              <a href="mailto:info@jpadsolutions.com">info@companyIwork.com</a>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 text-center">
            <a href="#"><i class="bi bi-facebook"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="bi bi-twitter"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="bi bi-instagram"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="bi bi-linkedin"></i></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 text-center">
            <p>© 2022 - TheCompanyIWork Limited</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

NOTE: The snippet above does not consider your stylesheet, so be cautious your stylesheet might override some bootstrap styles

SUGGESTION: Also consider reading bootstrap colors from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/colors/